# Undefined Index PHP-Mysql

Tags: php, mysql

tengo el siguiente error me aparece que no estan definidos unos indices 
ingreso y vencimiento ambos estan como tipo fecha 'date' en en formulario 
probe la consulta en Sqlyog y no muestra error alguno entonces no se que pueda ser en los campos del formulario tienen los nombres de ingreso y vencimiento

Bueno tengo 2 tablas una llamada medicamento_detalle y otra llamada medicamento

medicamento_detalle
id_medicamento_detalle-llave primaria
id_medicamento fk
cantidad
lote
fecha_ingreso
fecha_vencimiento

medicamento
id_medicamento
medicamento

```html
<?php $resulttt = mysqli_query($connect, "SELECT p.id_medicamento_detalle,m.medicamento,p.cantidad,p.lote,p.fecha_ingreso,p.fecha_vencimiento
FROM medicamento_detalle AS p
INNER JOIN medicamento AS m
ON p.id_medicamento=m.id_medicamento
WHERE id_medicamento_detalle='$id_medicamento_detalle'");
  $r = mysqli_fetch_array($resulttt);
  $id_medicamento = $r['medicamento'];
  $cantidad = $r['cantidad'];
  $lote = $r['lote'];
  $fecha_ingreso = $r['ingreso'];
  $fecha_vencimiento = $r['vencimiento'];
  
   ?>
```

```html
<form method="POST" action="update_control.php">
    
      <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="medicamento">Medicamento</label>
                    <select style="width:450px" id="medicamento" name="medicamento">
                      <option>Seleccione</option>
                      <?php 
                      $query = "SELECT * FROM medicamento ORDER BY medicamento";
                      $medi=$connect->query($query); 
                      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($medi)) { ?>
                      <option value="<?php echo $row['id_medicamento']; ?>"><?php echo $row['medicamento']; ?></option>
                       <?php } ?>
                    </select>
                  </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="cantidad" class="form-control" placeholder="Cantidad" required="" value="<?php echo $cantidad; ?>">
        </div><!-- form-group -->

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" name="lote" class="form-control" placeholder="Lote" required="" 
          value="<?php echo $lote; ?>">
        </div><!-- form-group -->

        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="date" name="ingreso" class="form-control" required="" 
          value="<?php echo $fecha_ingreso; ?>">
        </div>

      <!-- form-group -->
      <div class="form-group">
          <input type="date" name="vencimiento" class="form-control"  required="" 
          value="<?php echo $fecha_vencimiento; ?>">
        </div>
    <!--form-group -->
    
  <!-- form-group -->
 
        <!-- form-group -->
        <input type="hidden" name="id_medicamento_detalle" value="<?php echo $id_medicamento_detalle; ?>">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="submit" name="update" class="btn btn-info" value="Editar Control">
        </div><!-- form-group -->
       </form><!-- form -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Los nombres de los campos en la consulta no son iguales al índice que usas para llamarlos en el array.

```
$fecha_ingreso = $r['fecha_ingreso']; //$fecha_ingreso = $r['ingreso'];
$fecha_vencimiento = $r['fecha_vencimiento']; //$fecha_vencimiento = $r['vencimiento'];
```

Comment: al ponerlos asi no envia nada no se porque si pongo fecha_ingreso tambien me toca poner fecha_ingreso en el valor que esta en el formulario en name= ?

Comment: No te entiendo, haces una consulta con unos nombres de campo y recorres el resultado almacenado en $r, los nombres de los campos en la consulta select determinan cómo accedes a sus valores, el índice debe llevar el nombre del select. Otra cosa es el valor que traes del formulario, no necesitas cambiarlo.

Comment: Gracias lo pude solucionar fue de gran ayuda puse en fecha_vencimiento y le puse como un alias y le puse vencimiento para no molestar tanto como te puedo dar puntos siendo casi nuevo ?

Comment: no te pude dar puntos no me alcanza la reputacion pero te di chulito :D

Comment: De nada, con que la dez por resuelta ya llega. ;)